# Network call causes hybrid app to crash in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have created hybrid app using cordova. We have 1 post service which gives list of cities. When app hits the service, app gets crashed. This network call working fine in android and iOS.

Message is :

> An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.
>
> Source is :
>
> Microsoft.Phone.Interop
>
> Stack Trace is :
>
> at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(Int32 hr)
>   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(String
>   scriptName, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName,
>   String[] args)    at
>   WPCordovaClassLib.CordovaLib.XHRHelper.HandleCommand(String
>   commandStr)    at
>   WPCordovaClassLib.CordovaView.CordovaBrowser_ScriptNotify(Object
>   sender, NotifyEventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.FireScriptNotifyEvent(String
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.ReversePInvokeThunk.OnScriptNotify(Int32
>   webBrowserControlId, String value)

I made wp8 native app and just wrote above network call. here it works fine and returns list of cities. But in hybrid app it directly crashes app as soon as it hits service.

As app is hybrid, I do not find any way to debug this issue.